# Reinstalling ubuntu beside win8

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

I have dualboot: Ubuntu 12.04.2 and Windows8
I want to reinsall Ubuntu.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Pop in your Ubuntu cd or usb, then hit Install Ubuntu. When it presents you with options such as "Erase Ubuntu and Reinstall", "Erase Windows 8 and install Ubuntu", "Upgrade Ubuntu",  make sure you are erasing your old Ubuntu installation and not Windows 8.

Take a look at this image:
http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/extra/LINUX/large/ubuntu1104installation-large_003.jpg

You need to click "Upgrade Ubuntu".

Comment: When I install Ubutnu, does it cause exchange or something else in partition where is windows?