# Reinstalling Ubuntu on a partitioned hard drive

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, system-installation, reinstalling

I had Win7 installed on my laptop, then created a partition and installed Ubuntu on it so I can dual boot.
However, being pretty new to Ubuntu I have messed around too much and would simply like to reinstall Ubuntu (I still have the .iso on a DVD). I don't care about backing up anything  have on it. Is it a risk-free process just restarting with the DVD in and reinstalling from there?

I've haven't found a tutorial for this anywhere online, but I have found stories of people with Windows 8 (partitioned with Ubuntu) trying this and wiping out Windows.

By the way, if you can suggest a better way of getting back to a fresh installation of Ubuntu without reinstalling from the disk, I'd be happy to that too, but again, I couldn't find any way of doing that from searching the forums.

Thanks.

Comment: when you were presented with the setup, what had you chosen? `install alongside windows` or `something else` ? had you manually setup the partition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reinstalling ubuntu beside win8](http://askubuntu.com/questions/316065/reinstalling-ubuntu-beside-win8)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you should do:

1. Boot from the DVD.
2. Go through the initial steps but choose **Something Else** when you are presented with options on the installation type. [It's usually the last option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4ADd.png).
3. Look for your Ubuntu partition in the list. Identify it by its size, type, or the comments in the last column. Its type is probably `ext4` and the last column could read `Ubuntu` or something. That's the partition.
4. Double click the partition. Pick "Use as" `ext4`, type in `/` for the "Mounting Point", and click OK. Check the `format?` box next to it so that the partition will be formatted.
5. Now, your table should read mount point `/` next to your old Ubuntu partition, and you might see a partition with type `swap` somewhere. Click next.

This will format that partition (because we chose `format?`) and install Ubuntu on it (because we made it mount point `/`). If you follow these steps, nothing will happen to your other partitions (such as Windows).

Comment: wow. You know what @Ali, you wont believe, it feels like, you stole the words from my mind. i wrote it the exact same way and the exact words and formatting. i left my desk midway to bring myself a cup of tea and i find an answer posted. i thought to myself that i haven't posted it and when i scrolled down, i saw your name. :) Then i discarded my draft.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I'm glad there is a consensus on this. I've posted my own answer which is the steps I took to solve it (before revisiting AskUbuntu to see your answer).

Answer (score 1):

My solution was:

1. Boot into Windows 7
2. Navigate to Disk Management in System
3. Right click and remove the old Ubuntu partition(s) that you don't want any more (I made just one to install Ubuntu, but that had some how become 2). You might have to right click again and delete, until there is a partition left labelled 'Unallocated'.
4. Now you can restart and install Ubuntu from the DVD as you did the first time.

Done. It worked just fine.